# Bad request data: "Requests with 'Connection: Upgrade' cannot have content in the request body." when doing POST request to APi

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have created a simple .NET core Web API, which runs perfectly on localhost.
Whenever i deploy the docker image to our server (Jelastic) and POST to the only POST endpoint i get failure.

The error is as follows:

```
 INFO  02:41:14 Connection id "0HLOLOJQ1QFRM" bad request data: "Requests with 'Connection: Upgrade' cannot have content in the request body."
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Requests with 'Connection: Upgrade' cannot have content in the request body.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw(RequestRejectionReason reason)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1MessageBody.For(HttpVersion httpVersion, HttpRequestHeaders headers, Http1Connection context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.CreateMessageBody()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

All GET requests succeeds without a problem.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<List<string>> Post([FromBody]Dictionary<string, string> data)
{
    //LOGIC
}
```

I don't think there is a reverse proxy ([NGINX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556780/asp-net-core-2-0-unable-to-post-to-database) or similar) and everything is handled by Kestrel.

My requests is:

```
POST /api/word HTTP/1.1
Host: *our server*
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 9d575404-6347-4783-a03f-cba29f9113e8,b8a94c5d-1ee5-42c4-a2e4-348c9af0e064
Host: *our server*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 110
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

{
"customerName": "test-entries",
"reportPeriod": "test-entries"
}
```

This fails when using CURL as well.
What could be overlooked here?

Comment: Are you sure it works locally? For `[FromBody]`, it expected the request with `Content-Type: application/json`, but you sent request with `Content-Type: text/plain`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it looks like i took the wrong request from our test-set, i have updated the request but still no difference in outcome.

Comment: What is your current request?

Comment: You certain that Jelastic doesn't have a reverse proxy running?

Comment: @mjwills it was indeed that.

Answer (score 1):

It appears it indeed was a Jelastic proxy as @mjwills stated in the comments.
In Jelastic i have registered an endpoint that maps port 80 in the container to 11000 publicly and the problems seems solved. It appears that the proxy/mapping/rerouting in Jelastic altered the request.